# Inserting a linux module on TI OMAP 3530 for older file system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, omap

Where can I download the OMAP 3530 file system for kernel version #2.6.31-rc7-omap1-06331-g757f531  or how can I create one from the source?

File System provided by TI is for kernel version is 2.6.29-rc3-omap1. (based on /lib/modules/).

I built new uImage (kernel) of version # 2.6.31-rc7-omap1-06331-g757f531 and a module (.ko) file so when I tried to insert my module, it complains:

root@omap3evm:~# modprobe -r pci.ko
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.31-rc7-omap1-06331-g757f531/modules.dep: No such file or directory

because file system has only folder '2.6.29-rc3-omap1' under /lib/modules.

I tried to insert the module with "-f" or "--force-vermagic"   and   "--force-modversion", does not work.

Comment: You have to build everything by yourself. I recommend to look at Buildroot project http://buildroot.uclibc.org/about.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build separate file system for specific kernel version. File system is generic and it should work with all kernel. Use following command to install specific kernel version into filesystem.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-  uImage
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-  modules
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=<target filesystem> modules_install
```

This will create new directory with kernel version into /lib/modules/ folder.